# DataGridView.RowLeave fires before a Form button.MouseClick

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, mouseclick-event

I can't find anything about this anywhere:
I have a form with a `DataGridView` and a few Buttons. When a row of the *datagridview* is selected, and I click a button (on the form), `dgv.RowLeave` triggers before anything else. It triggers even before Click or MouseClick.

That kind of makes sense, but the problem is that the *sender* of `RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)` is the *DataGridView*, not the button. So it doesn't seem to be possible to know at that point what button was clicked on, because sender and e both refer to the DataGridView, not the Form nor the Buttons.

The Click event is triggered, but only after *RowLeave* was processed.

So is there any way to know where the user clicked, before *RowLeave* does other things (in my case, resulting in the **Button.Click to be never handled**), or then from within RowLeave?

```
Class MainForm
' The form contains a DataGridView and btnQuit (and other buttons)

Private Sub dgv_RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowLeave

  ProgrammaticallyDoRowValidation(dgv.CurrentRow.Index) ' This does validation and more. 
  ' But if btnQuit is clicked, I need to know here, or before RowLeave is
  ' triggered and NOT do this row validation.
  ' ...
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
  Dim frm As Form
  frm = CType(sender, Form)
  ' Translated from Sach's comment below. Code never reaches this event
  '(RowLeave prevents it).
End Sub

Private Sub Quit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.MouseClick

  QuitPgm() ' Contains some more stuff.
  ' Also never executed, because RowLeave is handled first.

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The *sender* for any and all DGV events is going to be a DGV.  Always.

Comment: The buttons are on the Form, though: how to capture these? Can't believe that, because one is on the dgv, there is no way to know what was clicked outside of the dgv.

Comment: The Click event and the RowLeave event are two separate events. Each event has its own sender. In a button's Click event, the sender should be the button itself.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a relevant snippet of your code in order to better understand your issue?

Comment: @Simo Thank you. Do I always have to manually add 4 spaces in front of code? Cumbersome...

Comment: @CeSinge you can select all your codes, then click the {} symbol. It appends spaces into your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `WinForms` here, but the idea is the same.

So `Event`s are attached to `Control`s. A `Button` is a `Control`, so is a `DataGridView`. Then in the Code Behind you have `Event Handlers` which are essentially methods tied to `Control Events`.

So when you attach a `Click` event to a button, behind-the-scenes, `VB.NET` creates an `Event Handler` like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Now the `sender` is an object, but it's actually the `DataGrid` that is passed there. So contrary to your statement *So it doesn't seem to be possible to know at that point what button was clicked on* you CAN know if a button was clicked on. If it was, and if you have an event handler attached, it *will* get called. For example, this will show a `MessageBox` with the button text:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(btn.Text);
}
```

So if you want to know if the `Form` was clicked, attach a `Click` event handler:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = (Form)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(frm.Text);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work: both button1_click and Form1_click are triggered _after_ RowLeave. So in my case, these two events will never be handled because RowLeave (doing RowValidation and other stuff) prevents the code of the button to be ever executed. I'd want to have the button have priority, i.e. execute before the RowLeave.

Comment: These events are independent. 'DataGridView.RowLeave` occurs when focus leaves a particular row in the `DataGridView`. A `Button` or `Form` click happens when the user clicks on those controls. They have nothing to do with each other. If you never had focus to the `DataGridView` the `FormLeave` won't even happen. And there's no reason why validations etc on the `FormLeave` event should stop other events being fired. Maybe you should show your code.

Comment: Added, in summary, above.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to say. Click event occurs when user clicks the button, and RowLeave occurs when row selection changed. They are not dependent on each other. Your code will NOT reach button event after a RowLeave. Are you expecting it to?

Comment: This is not what happens: if my code in RowLeave does nothing, RowLeave will _first_ be handled right after the click of the mouse on the button, _then, only after that_ the Click event. Also, they are dependent in two ways: a) because there is a sequence: always RowLeave before the Click is handled and b) code in the RowLeave event results in Click _not_ being handled. That's why  I'd want either to see the sequence RowLeave then Click inverted, _or_ a way to detect, in RowLeave, if RowLeave results from a mouseclick on a button, or something else. I will add the sequence of events tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you prevent the button click in your RowLeave event, but I think you should use RowValidating event to validate the DataGridView. Let's say we have a DataGridView with only 1 column and a Button. The validation is the column value must not higher than 100. If we put the validation in the RowValidating event, the validation is triggered after the Leave event but before Validated event. If the validation fails, the subsequence events are not fired.

```
Public Class Form1

    Function ProgrammaticallyDoRowValidation(i As Integer) As Boolean
        If Convert.ToInt32(dgv(0, i).Value) > 100 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub dgv_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowValidating
        If Not ProgrammaticallyDoRowValidation(dgv.CurrentRow.Index) Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Buton clicked")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Try running the code and enter a value higher than 100 in the column. You can't click the button because it fails the validation. But if you set the `Button`'s `CausesValidation` property to `False`, the validation won't be triggered.

The order of event according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.7.2) is like this:

> When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and
>   so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by
>   setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current
>   form, focus events occur in the following order: Enter -> GotFocus ->
>   Leave -> Validating -> Validated -> LostFocus
>
> When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus
>   method, focus events occur in the following order: Enter -> GotFocus
>   -> LostFocus -> Leave -> Validating -> Validated

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to know where the user clicked, before RowLeave
>   does other things (in my case, resulting in the Button.Click to be
>   never handled), or then from within RowLeave?
>
> ```
> Private Sub dgv_RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowLeave
>
>   ProgrammaticallyDoRowValidation(dgv.CurrentRow.Index) ' This does validation and more. 
>   ' But if btnQuit is clicked, I need to know here, or before RowLeave is
>   ' triggered and NOT do this row validation.
>   ' ...
> End Sub
> ```

This is a bit of a kludge solution, but within the [DataGridView.RowLeave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave?view=netframework-4.7.2) event, you can check if the [ContainerControl.ActiveControl Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see if the currently active control is the one you want to test for.  In this case the `ContainerControl` is the `Form`.

```
Private Sub dgv_RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowLeave

    ProgrammaticallyDoRowValidation(dgv.CurrentRow.Index) ' This does validation and more. 
    ' But if btnQuit is clicked, I need to know here, or before RowLeave is
    ' triggered and NOT do this row validation.
    ' ...
    If Me.ActiveControl Is btnQuit Then
        ' do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I was looking for. Me.ActiveControl and it's properties expose all the properties of the true caller, the button, not the DGV. Other properties can be used, like .text, .name. That said, maybe I should review my code more fundamentally as you suggest... I can't mark this answer +1... way to many pointless restrictions on this site.